# What will happen when a WPF control will be removed from parent?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, user-controls

What happens to a WPF user control when this function is Called: `uiElement.Childen.Remove(foo)` Is it marked at GC to be removed or it just hangs in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *there are no other references* to `foo`, it should be available for garbage collection.

You may try to add `Finalizer` to check it:

```
class MyElement
{
    // ...
    ~MyElement()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("~MyElement()");
    }
}
```

and call

```
uiElement.Childen.Remove(foo);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
Console.WriteLine("After GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()");
```

Then check if you see `"~MyElement"` before `"After GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()"` in the output window.

Comment: Thanks for claryfing that :)